# javascript toggle menu on and off

Tags: javascript, html

Hey everyone I have been struggling with the nav menu and getting it to toggle on and off, it seems to be turning on and off in the dev tools but the li links don't disappear, I have tried rewriting the code, but still can't get it to work, I double checked to make sure i was selecting the right elements, please if anyone can help I would sincerely appreciate it!
Thank You
here is the code:

```js
const showMenu = (toggleId, navId) => {
  const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    nav = document.getElementById(navId)

  if (toggle && nav) {
    toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
      nav.classList.toggle("show");
    })
  }
};

showMenu('nav-toggle', 'nav-menu');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<header class="1-header" id="header">
  <nav class="nav bd-grid">
    <div class='nav_toggle' id='nav-toggle'>
      <i class="bx bxs-grid"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="nav_logo">Roby</a> -->
    <a href="#" class="nav_logo">Sneaker Warehouse</a>

    <div class='nav_menu' id='nav-menu'>
      <ul class="nav_list">
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#home" class="nav_link active">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#featured" class="nav_link">Featured</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#women" class="nav_link">Women</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#new" class="nav_link">New</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="./shop.html" class="nav_link">Shop</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="nav_shop">
      <i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<script src="practice.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add `toggle.classList.toggle("show")` next to the `nav` toggle one.

Comment: Do you have CSS that changes the visibility of the nav menu based on the `show` class?

Comment: You need to copy `practice.css` into the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by reading one of the comments on this post. you forgot to add the css.

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<header class="1-header" id="header">
  <nav class="nav bd-grid">
    <div class='nav_toggle' id='nav-toggle'>
      <i class="bx bxs-grid"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="nav_logo">Roby</a> -->
    <a href="#" class="nav_logo">Sneaker Warehouse</a>

    <button class='nav_menu' id='nav-menu'>
      <ul class="nav_list">
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#home" class="nav_link active">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#featured" class="nav_link">Featured</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#women" class="nav_link">Women</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#new" class="nav_link">New</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="./shop.html" class="nav_link">Shop</a></li>
      </ul>
    </button>

    <div class="nav_shop">
      <i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<script src="practice.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
```

js

```
const showMenu = (toggleId, navId) => {
  const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    nav = document.getElementById(navId)

  if (toggle && nav) {
    toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
      nav.classList.toggle("show");
      toggle.classList.toggle("show");
    })
  }
};

showMenu('nav-toggle', 'nav-menu');
```

css

```
.nav_menu {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: initial;
}
```

Comment: Hey Thank you SoloOrchid, Barmar and Mister Jojo, I finally got it to work, I appreciate all your help!!!.

Comment: You are welcome, if my answer helped anything you can feel free to upvote it.